# Jquery unbind method is deprecated after 3.0. So, how to implement it After Jquery 3.0?

Tags: jquery

I checked on the following link:

https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

They say that unbind event of Jquery is deprecated after Jquery 3.0. Deprecated since 3.0. Use `{@link JQuery.off }` instead of it. But I did not get a proper example to implement it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Here is detailed instructions about this https://www.andismith.com/blogs/2011/11/on-and-off/

Comment: Presumably you've also switched all your .binds to .ons? Isn't .unbind to .off analogous to that?

Comment: There are alot of examples about off in jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: There are indeed examples on https://api.jquery.com/off/ – which part exactly is unclear?